# Cannot see products in shop page - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can't seem to see any of my products in the shop page and the search function returns 0 results, but in the admin console I can see all the products...

I have checked that catalog visibility is set to Catalog/search.

Any ideas?

Comment: deactivate all other plugins except woocommerce to see it helps

Comment: Diabled everything, still the same

Comment: Interesting, when I change the theme it all starts working again....

How can I see whats causing the theme to stop the results showing?

Comment: just rename the template folder/woocommerce folder in theme to some other

Comment: "You have searched the blog archives for ‘usb’. If you are unable to find anything in these search results, you can try one of these links."

This is what I'm getting now, looks like its not searching my products?

Comment: The fact that we can't see it ourselves as well as your backend makes it unlikely to find resolution through here. This site is best for when you have code related issues rather than a site that just doesn't work. It's like saying "my car doesn't work" but not allowing the user to see the car to diagnose and all we have to go on is nothing happens when you turn the key.

Comment: Try checking and running System Status option of woocommerce and check what issues it shows. Refer this link to troubleshoot http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-self-service-guide/